# Validation in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, validation, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to validate existing record in django rest framework and following the  [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/)

In my serializer class I have my class like .

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Part

class PartSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    part_id = serializers.CharField(required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Part.objects.all())] )
    capacity = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    price = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)


    def create(self, validated_data):

        """
        Create and return a new `Part` instance, given the validated data.
        """
      #  try:part_exist = Part.objects.get(part_id = validated_data['part_id'])
      #  except:part_exist = None
      #  if part_exist:
      #      raise  serializers.ValidationError('Part name already exist.')
      #  else:
        return Part.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

But  I am always getting  error `name 'UniqueValidator' is not defined`

I don't know how to import this as it is not mentioned in doc .Please  help me out how to do this .And if it is not possible should I write own validation logic under views ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the `UniqueValidator` from the `rest_framework.validators` module:

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
```

Comment: Thanks @catavaran they have not mentioned anywhere in validations page

Comment: Yep, documentation is not clear here.  They have a small link to the `validators.py` source at the top right corner of the page http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

Comment: Or use IDE with auto import feature.